# Is the map $S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\cong S^{2n}$ essential?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

This question is motivated solely by idle curiousity.

There is a natural map $p:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ mapping a point on $S^{2n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ to the unique complex line it spans in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

It is well know that $p$ gives $S^{2n+1}$ the structure of an $S^1$ bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  From this, one gets a long exact sequence in homotopy groups.  Since $\pi_k(S^1)  = 0$ for $k > 1$, one sees from this that $p_\ast :\pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n+1})\rightarrow \pi_{2n+1}(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ is an isomorphism.  In particular, $p$ is homotopically nontrivial.

Likewise, notice that by collapsing the $2n-2$ skeleton of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to a point, one gets a map $q:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\cong S^{2n}$, the latter homeomorphism coming from the usual cellular picture of $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  It is easy to see that this map induces an isomorphism on $H_{2n}$, so is also homotopically nontrivial.

My question is about the composition $q\circ p : S^{2n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n}$.

> Is the composition $q\circ p:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n}$ also homotopically nontrivial?

Here are some data points:

1. The composition of two homotopically nontrivial maps need not be homotopically nontrivial.  The simplest examples are probably the following:  If $X$ and $Y$ are both noncontractible, then any of the "natural" inclusions $i:X\rightarrow X\times Y$ is homotopically nontrivial, the projection $X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ is homotopically nontrivial, but the composition is homotopically trivial.
2. In the case $n=1$, $q$ doesn't actually collapse anything - it's a homeomorphism.  Thus, in this case $q \circ p$ is homotopically nontrivial.  (In fact, it's known to generate $\pi_3(S^2)$).
3. For higher $n$, $\pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, so the square of $q\circ p$ in $\pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n})$ is homotopically trivial.
4. If we use $\mathbb{R}P^n$ instead of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, we end up getting a map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$.  This map is homotopically nontrivial iff $n$ is odd, where it acts by multiplication by 2 on the top homology group.

Thanks, and please feel free to retag as appropriate!

Comment: A minor point, I think $q$ should be the quotient map $q:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, not the homeomorphism $\mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n}$. Otherwise the composition $q\circ p$ is not defined.

Comment: @Sebastian:  You're right - I didn't correctly write what I was thinking :-).  I'll edit in one moment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I see, the cone of the map $S^{2n+1}→S^{2n}$ is precisely $CP^{n+1}/CP^{n−1}$. So we have to distinguish the latter from $S^{2n+2}\vee S^{2n}$ (at least when $n\geq 2$, since then we are already in the stable range).

Let $s: CP^{n+1}\rightarrow CP^{n+1}/CP^{n-1}$ be the projection.
We have $H^*(CP^{n+1}; Z/2) = Z/2[x]/(x^{n+2})$ and there are $u$, $v\in H^*(CP^{n+1}/CP^{n-1}; Z/2)$ such that $s^*(u) = x^n$, $s^*(v) = x^{n+1}$.
Then: 
$$s^*(Sq^2(u)) = Sq^2(x^n) = nx^{n+1} = ns^*(v).$$
Hence, $Sq^2(u) = n v$. This implies that the map is essential if $n$ is odd.

Using the complex $J$-homomorphism, one can also show that the map is stably trivial if $n$ is even. For background see for instance Hatcher's VB&K-Theory.
Given a map $f\colon S^1\rightarrow U(n)$, one can construct a new map

$$
Jf\colon S^1* S^{2n-1}\rightarrow D^{2n}/S^{2n-1}, (z, t, (z_1, \ldots, z_n))\mapsto \sqrt{1-t^2}f(z)(z_1, \ldots z_n).$$
Actually, usually $t$ is used instead of $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ in the last formula but this doesn't matter. Here, $X*Y$ is the topological join.
The important point is that this yields a group homomorphism $J\colon \pi_1(U(n))\rightarrow \pi_1^{st}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, which is surjective, since one can check that $J([S^1\subset U(n)])$ is the Hopf element.
Note that
$$
D^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n, z=(z_1, \ldots, z_n)\mapsto [z_1: \ldots : z_{n} : \sqrt{1-|z|^2}]
$$
is a homeomorphism away from $S^{2n-1}$ and induces a homeomorphism 
$$D^{2n}/S^{2n-1}\cong \mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}.$$

Under this identification, one checks that the map 
$S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}\cong D^{2n}/S^{2n-1}$ in question is given by
$(z_1, \ldots, z_{n+1}) \mapsto |z_{n+1}|/z_{n+1} (z_1, \ldots, z_n)$, if $z_{n+1}\neq 0$ and $(z_1, \ldots, z_{n+1})\mapsto [S^{2n-1}]$ otherwise.
Finally, we have a homeomorphism
$$S^1*S^{2n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n+1}, (z, t, (z_1, \ldots, z_n))\mapsto (\sqrt{1-t^2} z_1, \ldots, \sqrt{1-t^2} z_n, tz).$$
Composition with the former map, yields
$$S^1*S^{2n-1}\rightarrow D^{2n}/S^{2n-1}, (z, t, (z_1, \ldots, z_n))\mapsto \bar{z}\sqrt{1-t^2}(z_1, \ldots, z_n).$$

This is precisely $J(\bar{i}_n)$, where $\bar{i}_n\colon S^1\rightarrow U(n)$ maps $z$ to the matrix representing multiplication by $\bar{z}$.
Then $[\bar{i}_n] = -n*[S^1\subset U(n)]\in \pi_1(U(n))$, consequently, $J$ being a homomorphism, $J([\bar{i}_n]) = n[\eta]$ which is zero if $n$ is even and non-zero if $n$ is odd.

Comment: This is going to take me awhile to digest.  I'm familiar with Steenrod operations, but not too familiar with K-theory.  To begin with, however, I'm confused at the very beginning: If the cone is $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$, doesn't this already give that the map is essential?  This follows since $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2n+2}$ (map the collapsed $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ to the south pole of $S^{2n+2}$ and map the attaching disc to all other points of $S^{2n+2}$), so, in particular, not homotopy equivalent to $S^{2n+2}\vee S^{2n}$.

Comment: (I won't be able to look at this again for another 4 or 5 hours or so.  Sorry!)

Comment: The cone isn't $CP^{n+1}/CP^n$ but $CP^{n+1}/CP^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I agree that that is the mapping cone and I understand your argument in the case of $n$ odd with Steenrod squares.  Unfortunately, I literally have only heard of Adam's relations and I know very little about K-theory in general, so that part's out of reach for now.  If you don't mind, I'm going to hold of accepting this answer for a day or so in case someone comes up with a simpler argument that $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ and $S^{2n+2}\vee S^{2n}$ are homotopically distinct.  But thank you again!

Comment: Sure, I'd like to see an easier proof, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really expect there to be one.  Cohomology ring calculations are useless for trivial reasons, and the next obvious invariant is Steenrod operations.  You've now exhausted the utility of all those.  The only remaining hope I have is that maybe $\pi_{2n+1}$ is different for the two spaces.  Unfortunately, I don't really know how to compute $\pi_{2n+1}$ in either case.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the J-homomorphism than K-theory, so I like your new approach better.  Also, I just posted my own approach which uses framed cobordism theory.  I've accepted yours since I wanted to thank you for all the effort you've put in.

Comment: I am sorry for being suspicious. I think the fact that the map is null-homotopic for $n$ even is easier. In any case you have this map $f: S^{2n+1} \to S^{2n}$ and if $n \geq 3$ this is a stable map, hence either zero or $\eta$. Hence the Cone of this map is either $\Sigma^n(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ or $S^{2n+2}\vee S^{2n}$. In both cases you can detect the homotopy type of that space by $Sq^2$ which is either zero or not. So I think for $n$ even the map you describe is null-homotopic for these simple reasons.

Comment: Ah excellent! The map is stable for $n \geq 2$, isn't it? Of course, you need the $2n-2$nd suspension of $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Comment: Though, the advantage of the $J$-homomorphism over the other methods is, as far as I see, that the same formulae as above work to show the analouges for the maps $S^{4n+3}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{H}P^{n-1}\cong S^{4n}\in\pi_3^{st}$ and $S^{8n+7}\rightarrow \mathbb{O}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{O}P^{n-1}\cong S^{8n}\in \pi_7^{st}$.

Comment: The system apparently doesn't allow you to award bounties without waiting a bit - sorry it took so long!  Also, note there are no $\mathbb{O}P^n$ for $n\geq 3$ due to nonassociativity of the octonians.

Comment: yes. you are right :)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Thanks for pointing out the error and the points!

Comment: Nice! Do you have some reference for this kind of computations? Or is it yours?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another proof coming from Pontrjagin's framed cobordisms.

We'll use the following result due to Pontrjagin, which can be found, for example, in Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable viewpoint:

> For any closed $n$-manifold $M$, the homotopy classes of maps into $S^k$, denoted $[M,S^k]$ is in 1-1 correspondence with framed (n-k)-submanifolds of $M$ (submanifolds with trivial normal bundle and a particular choice of trivialization) modulo the equivalence of framed cobordism (where the cobordism is required to be a submanifold of $M$ as well).

The correspondence is as follows:  given a homotopy class of map $[f]:M\rightarrow S^k$, choose a smooth representative $f$.  Choose any regular value $p$.  Then the associated submanifold is $f^{-1}(p)$ and the framing is pulled back from a choice of oriented basis for $T_p S^k$.

In our particular application, we want to understand a map from $S^{2n+1}$ to $S^{2n}$.  By dimension count, the inverse image will be a disjoint union of circles.  By drawing pictures in $\mathbb{R}^3$, one can easily convince oneself that any number of circles is frame cobordant to a single circle.

Our particular map is already smooth, at least, away from an equitorial $S^{2n-1}$ (and it can be homotoped to be smooth there as well).  Since the map from $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to $S^{2n}$ is generically $1-1$, this reduces the problem to considering the induced framing on any Hopf circle.

The normal bundle of the Hopf circle $(e^{i\theta}, 0,....,0)\in S^{2n+1} (\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{2n+2})$ is a $2n$-dimensional vector bundle.  Hence, it is determined by a choice of $S^1\rightarrow SO(2n)$.  Note that if two choices are homotopic, the corresponding framings are frame cobordant:  One can take a cylinder over $S^1$ where the $"t"$ coordinate of the cylinder corresponds to the time parameter in the homotopy.  This is clearly embeddable in $S^{2n+1}$.

We conclude that the map $S^{2n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n}$ is essential iff the corresponding map $S^1\rightarrow SO(2n)$ is.  It remains to compute that map.

To that end, let $v_i$ denote the vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ whose only nonzero coordinate (in the $i$th slot), is $1$ and consider the basis $$\{v_2, iv_2, ..., v_n, iv_n$$ of $(i,0,...,0)^\bot \subseteq T_{(1,0...,0)} S^{2n+1}$.  It's easy to see that the framing at the point $(e^{i\theta},0,...,0)$ in the Hopf circle (which is pulled back from $\mathbb{C}P^n$ via the Hopf map) is given by the basis $$\{e^{i\theta}\,v_2, e^{i\theta}\,iv_2,...,e^{i\theta}\,v_n, e^{i\theta}\,iv_n\}.$$

In particular, in terms of this basis, the map $S^1\rightarrow SO(2n)$ maps $e^{i\theta}$ to the block diagonal matrix $$\operatorname{diag}(R(\theta), R(\theta), ..., R(\theta))$$ where $$R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$ is the standard rotation matrix.

It is relatively well known that we can homotope such a map to one of the form $$\operatorname{diag}(R(n\theta), 1, ..., 1)$$ which is very well known to be homotopically essential iff $n$ is odd.

Comment: This is also very nice. In the end, this is simply the inverse to the real $J$-homomorphism $J\colon\pi_1(SO)\rightarrow \pi_1^{st}$, of course.

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion that would end up being the case, but I wasn't sure.