# Show $\mathbb{CP^2/CP^1}$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{CP^4/CP^1}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

So, I have shown that the natural projection $\pi\colon \mathbb{CP^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{CP^n/CP^k}$ induces a monomorphism $\pi^*\colon H^*(\mathbb{CP^n/CP^k},\mathbb Z)\rightarrow H^*(\mathbb{CP^n},\mathbb Z) $. I would like to use this and the cohomology ring structure to show that we can't have a retract, but I am not exactly sure what the ring structure of $\mathbb{CP^2/CP^1}$ and  $\mathbb{CP^4/CP^1}$ are.

I know that $H^*(\mathbb{CP^n},\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[\gamma]/(\gamma^{n+1})$, where $|\gamma|=2$, so is $H^*(\mathbb{CP^n/CP^k},\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[\gamma^{k+1},\ldots ,\gamma^{n}]/(\gamma^{n+1})$?

This would give me $H^*(\mathbb{CP^2/CP^1},\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[\gamma^{2}]/(\gamma^{4})$ and $\pi^*(\gamma^2)\neq 0 \in H^*(\mathbb{CP^4/CP^1},\mathbb Z)$.

If this is true, then I think I can use that:

$0=\pi^*(0)=\pi^*(\gamma^2 \cup \gamma^2)=\pi^*(\gamma^2) \cup \pi^*(\gamma^2)\neq0$, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: treat $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^n/\mathbb{CP}^k)$ as a subring of $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ (included via $\pi^*$)

Comment: $\Bbb CP^2/\Bbb CP^1$ is homeomorphic to the $4$ sphere, and thus its cohomology ring is $\Bbb Z[t]/(t^2)$ with $t$ of degree $4$. If you use the long exact cohomology sequence $$\cdots\to \tilde{H}^*(\Bbb CP^4/\Bbb CP^1)\to H^*(\Bbb CP^4)\to H^*(\Bbb CP^1)\to \cdots$$ you can see that the cohomology ring of $\Bbb CP^4/\Bbb CP^1$ is $\Bbb Z[u,v]/(u^3,v^2,uv=vu=0)$ with $u$ in degree $4$ and $v$ in degree $6$. I'm not certain you can solve the problem only using the ring structure of cohomology.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat  As  you wrote $\mathbb{C}P^{2}/\mathbb{C}P^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{4}$ which  does  not satisfies the fixed point  property. As  a  possible alternative  proof for the  main question can one  prove  that $\mathbb{C}P^{4}/\mathbb{C}P^{1}$ has  the  fixed point  property?(Note  that  a retract  of  a  fixed point space is  a  fixed point space)

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe that, care of the first answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308318/is-the-map-s2n1-rightarrow-mathbbcpn-rightarrow-mathbbcpn-mathbb, that $\mathbb{C}P^3/\mathbb{C}P^1$ *does* retract onto $\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1$.  Sketch of proof:  According to the link, $\mathbb{C}P^3/\mathbb{C}P^1$ has the homotopy type of $S^4\vee S^6$, which clearly does retract on $S^4$.  (I don't know how to make all the details work).  The point is, this question could be quite subtle!

Comment: I'm confused- why doesn't Olivier's answer just answer the question. There is no nonzero element in degree 4 that squares to zero, so there's not even a nonzero map $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1) \rightarrow H^*(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1)$ let alone a retract.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm just answering this to get it off the unanswered list.  It's CW because I'm not doing anything but expanding on information in the comments).

As Olivier notes, $H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}[u,v]/u^3 = v^2  = uv = 0$ where $|u| = 4$ and $|v| = 6$.  This follows, as Olivier says, via the long exact sequence of the pair $(\mathbb{C}P^1,\mathbb{C}P^4)$, together with the fact that the inclusion map $\mathbb{C}P^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^4$ induces an isomorphism on $H^2$ and $H^0$, but is other wise the zero map.

Further, by the same technique, one easily sees that $H^\ast(\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{C}P^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}[t]/t^2$ where $|t| = 4$ (or one can also use the usual cell structure on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to see that $\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^4$).

Now, let $i:\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1$ be the inclusion.  Assume for a contradiction that $r:\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1$ is a retraction.

Then we have the formula $r\circ i = Id_{\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1}$.  In particular, $i^\ast r^\ast:H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1)\rightarrow H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1)$ is an isomorphism, which implies that $r^\ast:H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^2/\mathbb{C}P^1)\rightarrow H^\ast(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1)$ is an injection.  In particular, $r^\ast$ is not the zero map on $H^4$.

Now consider $r^\ast(t)$.  It must be some multiple of $u$, $r^\ast(t) = ku$, because $u$ generates $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^4/\mathbb{C}P^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Because $r^\ast$ is not the zero map, $k\neq 0$.

But now we have a contradiction:  $t^2 = 0$ so $0 = r^\ast(t^2) =r^\ast(t)^2 = (ku)^2 = k^2 u^2$ which forces $k = 0$.  Thus, there can not be a retraction $r$.