# A question on fixed point property

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Assume that $0<k<n-1$, Note that $\mathbb{C}P^{k}$ can be considered as a  closed subset of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$, in a natural way. We collapse $\mathbb{C}P^{k}$ to  a point. The resulting space is  denoted by $\mathbb{C}P^{n}/\mathbb{C}P^{k}$

**My fixed point question:**

> Does $\mathbb{C}P^{n}/\mathbb{C}P^{k}$ satisfies fixed point property?

This question is motivated by the following post:

[Show $\mathbb{CP^2/CP^1}$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{CP^4/CP^1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845057/show-mathbbcp2-cp1-is-not-a-retract-of-mathbbcp4-cp1#comment1754879_845057)